# How to select one specific frame

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am detecting vehicle from the video/camera , it work fine for detecting vehicle from the video/camera , but if suppose 6 sec video contain 2 vehicles and every vehicle contain 2 sec in the video than it extract 35+ frame for one vehicle and same case for the other vehicle , in simple words it extract all the frames from the video which contain vehicles but my requirement is to extract the only one frame of one vehicle like if 6 sec video contain 2 vehicles than i should extract the 2 frames which contain the whole vehicle and ignore all other frames . I already implemented entropy technique on it which make it better but still am getting too much frames of same vehicle . I want to know the technique in which i can extract the only frame which contain the whole vehicle and ignore all other frames which contain that vehicle (same vehicle)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you not only get a binary detection result (*"there is a car"*) but also some kind of spatial information (*"there is a car, and its bounding box is ..."*) then you can simply keep the frame that shows the most.

Something like this

```
best_frame = None
best_frame_score = 0.0
for frame in video:
    has_car, score = detect_car(frame)
    if has_car and score > best_frame_score:
        best_frame = frame
        best_frame_score = score
```

This assumes that the function `detect_car` returns a binary detection result and some score. The score could for example be the size of the bounding box.

Comment: i am not using bounding box technique , i am using surf with svm approach

Comment: Then you will of course need to calculate your score in some other way.

Comment: for that i am using entropy

Comment: Assuming that your entropy calculation works, and is a good measure on how much of the car is showing, use that as score.

Comment: but if on that score it shows that same car than ? like on 9.8 in one frame than on the next frame its also 9.8 than ?

Comment: If the score is the same, then you can either set the new frame as the best frame, or keep the old one. Doesn't matter. The important thing is that you only keep the frame that has the best score so far.